# run sharepoint powershell from c# on another PC?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

If the C# application is on the same server as sharepoint, I know we can use RunSpace to run the pwoershell script, but what if the C# app. and sharepoint server are on different PCs?

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, its possible, though messy.  In Powershell 2.0+, there's a feature called remote powershell, so you can effectively, via c# code, send Powershell commands to your local powershell instance, and use that to log into the remote instance.

A slightly less insane idea would be to simply create a web service on the remote machine, and have that run the remote powershell commands, from the web service.

And even less crazy idea is just to write a web service, and have that run code on the remote server.  : )

Good luck!

Comment: why the remote powershell is messy? is it security related? I will need run it from web application, does this have any obvious problem? thanks

Comment: I am not aware of how security works for running powershell from c# code.  I referred to it as messy because by running c# code to run powershell, to remote into another powershell machine, you've essentially just reinvented a web service, except with dependencies to powershell.  Just a figure of speech.

Comment: tried remote powershell, could not figure out how to make it work after 2 hours, it needs this/that changes in security settings. or maybe I just do not know how to do it, so I decided to write a web service to accept powershell script request and return results as xml. thanks.

Comment: remote powershell is not only messy.I was never able to setup properly in my work machines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are administrator on the remote box, you can try combining [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) and PowerShell.